# Passing Array Size along with pointer in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a function `foo` which processes the elements of an array whose size is user defined.

This function needs two parameters (not necessarily two separate arguments, or so do I think) - a pointer to the array and size of the array.

Are the three methods used below to the call the function valid?

```
int size;                      // Obtained from user 
int arr[size];    

foo(int (*arr)[size]);         // Will size be available as a vairable inside foo ?
foo(int (*arr)[],size);        
foo(int (*arr)[size],size);    // Is the 2nd parameter redundant here ?
```

Comment: Just pass the arguments to the method like this: `foo(arr,size);` Your function needs the following declaration: `void foo(int *array, int size);`

Comment: It works, but is it possible that i can access the size variable when I do the declaration as in method 1 , with its corresponding prototype declaration ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am very familiar with C but I never saw such a function call.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the size is not part of the array "object". Therefore, idiomatic C code passes the size of an array along with the array itself:

```
foo(arr, size);
```

for function

```
void foo(int arr[], int size);
```

(in the case of an array of integers).

See for example the `main` function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

(Note the arguments are reversed here.)

Comment: Shouldn't the declaration be :
void foo(int (*arr)[], int size);

Comment: In your question you have `int arr[size];`. In that case, `int arr[]` is the correct parameter declaration. Your declaration is "a pointer to an array of int". (And the `argv` from the `main` example is "an array of pointer to char".)

Comment: The size IS part of the array object . You can use `sizeof` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

3 approaches

**Pass array and size.**  (in any order.)  `b` will convert to the type and address of its first element - this becomes `a`.  `sizeof b/sizeof b[0]` will take on the value of 42 - useful to not repeat 42 all over the place.  `foo1` receives a pointer the the first element of the array and knows the array element count.

```
void foo1(int *a, size_t n);
size_t sz = 42;
int b[sz];
foo1(b, sizeof b/sizeof b[0]);
```

**Pass a pointer to an fixed sized array.**  The address of a fixed sized array is passed to `foo2()`.  `foo2()` can use `(*d)[0]` to access the first array element and `(*d)[41]` for the last element.  `foo2()` does not have to get receive the array element count, because the array element is known and fixed at 42.

```
void foo2(int (*d)[42]);
int e[42];
foo2(&e);
int f[13];
foo2(&f);  // invalid
```

**Pass the dimensions then a variable-length array.**  VLA is available in C99 and optionally in C11.  Notice that `foo3()` understands `d2` in accessing `arr[i][j]`, but does not know `arr` outer dimension is `d1`, even if `/* d1 */` was replaced with `d1`.

```
void foo3(size_t d1, size_t d2, char  arr[/* d1 */][d2]) {
  char x = 0;
  for (size_t i=0; i<d1; i++) {
    for (size_t j=0; j<d2; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = ++x;
    }
  }
}
void foop(size_t d1, size_t d2, char  arr[/* d1 */][d2]) {
  printf("ptr size:%zu,  sub-array size:%zu, element size:%zu |", 
      sizeof arr, sizeof arr[0], sizeof arr[0][0]);
  for (size_t i=0; i<d1; i++) {
    for (size_t j=0; j<d2; j++) {
      printf(" %d", arr[i][j]);
    }
  }
 printf("\n");
}

int foo2(int (*arr)[42]) {
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof *arr);
  return 0;
}

#define SZ(a)  (sizeof(a)/sizeof((a)[0]))
int main() {
  char  a[2][3];
  char  b[4][5];
  foo3(SZ(a),SZ(a[0]), a);
  foop(SZ(a),SZ(a[0]), a);
  foo3(SZ(b),SZ(b[0]), b);
  foop(SZ(b),SZ(b[0]), b);
}
```

Sample output

```
ptr size:4,  sub-array size:3, element size:1 | 1 2 3 4 5 6
ptr size:4,  sub-array size:5, element size:1 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

---

If a *fixed* array is needed, the array sizes may be omitted, depending on how the data is passed.

For a variable sized array, the dimensions need to be passed in some fashion.

Arrays may also be passed as a field of a `struct/union` - not shown.