# C how to iterate through function int array of unknown size as argument

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, while-loop, function-definition

I have the following code:

```
intlist* create_list(int *arr) {

    intlist* l = malloc(sizeof(intlist));

    while(*arr++) {
        l->sum += *arr; 
        //*arr++;
    }

    return l;
}

void printl(intlist* l) {
    printf("%d\n", l->sum);
}
```

When I print `*arr` inside the while loop it shows the correct value. The issue is after I come out of the function, create_list, and try to access the sum of the list, it is completely wrong. It is not, for example, 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 but rather something like -123871239012. What am I doing wrong?

I am not looking for a function to pass the array size to, because that is a very dangerous method to use, in my opinion and experience, most situations. I do not want to pass the size of the array because if I accidentally write "1239123" instead of "1239122" I might do something bad. Or even worse, if I accedentally write "1239123" instead of "123912" where I did not press the "3" in the last place it will have devastating effects.

Comment: I am now noticing that the while loop does not end when I reach the end of the array, but actually continue a few loops past. How might I solve this?

Comment: Post a complete program, not just fragments of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Array Size along with pointer in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617595/passing-array-size-along-with-pointer-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with the function `create_list`

```
intlist* create_list(int *arr) {

    intlist* l = malloc(sizeof(intlist));

    while(*arr++) {
        l->sum += *arr; 
        //*arr++;
    }

    return l;
}
```

The first one is that the data member `sum` was not initialized.

The second one is that the first element of the array is ignored due to the post-increment in the condition of the while loop

```
    while(*arr++) {
```

You should at least write

```
    while(*arr) {
        l->sum += *arr; 
        arr++;
    }
```

Pay attention to that you should check whether the memory was allocated successfully for an object of the type `intlist` before passing the control to the while loop.

The function expects that the array contains an element with the sentinel value equal to 0.

If the function must deal with arrays that do not have an element with the sentinel value then you have to declare a second parameter that will specify how many elements there are in the passed array.

Pay attention to that the first parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the passed array is not being changed within the function.

That is the function should be declared like

```
intlist * create_list( const int *arr, size_t n );
```

Answer (score 1):

Some errors:

```
while(*arr++) {
    l->sum += *arr; 
    //*arr++;
}
```

You will add the `*arr` **after** the arr incrementation.

To illustrate this problem: https://godbolt.org/z/5qe9cE

It has to be:

```
while(*arr) {
    l->sum += *arr++; 
    //*arr++;
}
```

the malloced memory is not initialized and structure members have undetermined values (it can be anything). Before the loop you need to

```
    l->sum = 0;
```

The array has to be `0` terminated for example

```
int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,0};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c8cPGs

Comment: Can I terminate with a non integer data? I might have a 0 in one of the number arrays, or basically any integer in my list is possible. I tried to add a `NAN` and I tried to add a `\0` to the end but that did not work.